# Doctrine mongo odm, annotate and query mongo ObjectId?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-odm

Hey There Im trying to map some documents in a mongodb and everything works perfect like this

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Id
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="string",name="text")
 */
protected $text;
```

but what if i have a field with a refference to another document with an Object id like :

```
...
other:ObjectId("823789473938ab"),
...
```

but what do i have to set as type ?

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="?",name="other")
 */
protected $other;
```

when i use the annotation above`@MongoDB\Id` 
it fails

i also tryed to use refferencene like

```
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Bundle1:Other")
```

leaving it argumentless always returns 0 when i do sth like this somewhere else

```
          $others=$dm
                 ->createQueryBuilder('Bundle1:Thing')
                 ->field('other')
                 ->equals('ObjectId("516c0061975a299edc44b419")')
                 ->getQuery()
                 ->execute()->count();
```

the query looks like :

```
doctrine.INFO: MongoDB query: {"find":true,"query":{"other":"ObjectId(\"516c0061975a299edc44b419\")"},"fields":[],"db":"maself","collection":"thing"}
```

so ofcourse theres a zero count, so part of the question also is how to query for all Things where other is a unique mongo id ?

for any help thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

```
@MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Bundle1:Other", simple=true)
```

The option "simple" true, should work for you! The default reference format for Doctrine is DBRef()

You can query it by :

```
$qb->field('other')->references($OtherObject)
```

or

```
$qb->field('other')->equals(new \MongoId('01243efe..'))
```

---

ObjectId() is the native field type for mongo in PHP its \MongoId

if you want use @MongoDB\Id you have to import :

```
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
```

Take care with cache when editing annotations !

Tips : If you make getId(), this method will return a string and not a \MongoId

Comment: hey,thanks! the @MongoDB\id works fine as i said . how would an annotation with getId() look like? i think i dont get it to work

Comment: thanks ? and how would my query look like to get an answer by other´s id ? 

 ->field('other')->equals("516c0061975a299edc44b419") this doesnt work

Comment: Not sure what happend, but "my account" downvoted this answer - I did no do it intentionally and cannot remove the downvote until @FabienMEYNARD edits the anser. So, can you edit it please and I can remove this unpleasant downvote? Sorry for that